# Create a table in R with column names that are a row of other table

Tags: r, dataset

I have a table named `data0`

```
    Sample  Gene    Frequency
1   sample1 gene1   18
2   sample1 gene2   1
3   sample1 gene3   1
4   sample1 gene4   14
5   sample1 gene5   8
6   sample2 gene1   7
7   sample2 gene4   10
8   sample2 gene5   4
9   sample3 gene1   10
10  sample3 gene3   3
11  sample3 gene6   1
12  sample3 gene4   9
```

I need to create another table named `data1` where the Column Name corresponds to the rows of one of the columns (gene). The result should be:

```
    Sample    Gene1 Gene2   Gene3   Gene4   Gene5   Gene6
1   Sample 1    18    1       1      14       8      NA
2   Sample 2    7     NA      NA     10       4      NA
3   Sample 3    10    NA      3      9        NA     1
```

Comment: check out `base::reshape` or `tidyr::pivot_wider` or `data.table::dcast` or `reshape2::dcast`

Answer (score 1):

One approach is `pivot_wider` from `tidyr`:

```
library(tidyr)

data1 <- pivot_wider(data0,names_from = Gene, values_from = Frequency)
data1
## A tibble: 3 x 7
#  Sample  gene1 gene2 gene3 gene4 gene5 gene6
#  <fct>   <int> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int>
#1 sample1    18     1     1    14     8    NA
#2 sample2     7    NA    NA    10     4    NA
#3 sample3    10    NA     3     9    NA     1
```

If you're really set on the column names, you could fix the Gene column first, with mutate:

```
library(dplyr)
data1 <- data0 %>% 
  mutate(Gene = paste0(toupper(substr(Gene, 1, 1)), substr(Gene, 2, nchar(as.character(Gene))))) %>%
  pivot_wider(names_from = Gene, values_from = Frequency)
data1
## A tibble: 3 x 7
#  Sample  Gene1 Gene2 Gene3 Gene4 Gene5 Gene6
#  <fct>   <int> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int>
#1 sample1    18     1     1    14     8    NA
#2 sample2     7    NA    NA    10     4    NA
#3 sample3    10    NA     3     9    NA     1
```

Comment: Yes. however, I'd like to add that the data looks finer in the first example than in the expected result.
I suggest RIA read about "tidy data" on google, especially if he intends to transform an inherited datastructure, before doing anything.

Comment: I didn't want to be rude with anyone. Your solution is fine. I'm new to answering on SO and thought the comments weren't as constrained as the answers. I wanted to help and sorry if I didn't express it the right way

Comment: That's fair. I agree with you that long form data is typically more useful.

Answer (score 0):

We can use `dcast` from `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
dcast(setDT(data0), Sample ~ Gene)
#    Sample gene1 gene2 gene3 gene4 gene5 gene6
#1: sample1    18     1     1    14     8    NA
#2: sample2     7    NA    NA    10     4    NA
#3: sample3    10    NA     3     9    NA     1
```

---

Or with `xtabs` from `base R`

```
xtabs(Frequency ~ Sample + Gene, data0)
```

#### data

```
data0 <- structure(list(Sample = c("sample1", "sample1", "sample1", "sample1", 
"sample1", "sample2", "sample2", "sample2", "sample3", "sample3", 
"sample3", "sample3"), Gene = c("gene1", "gene2", "gene3", "gene4", 
"gene5", "gene1", "gene4", "gene5", "gene1", "gene3", "gene6", 
"gene4"), Frequency = c(18L, 1L, 1L, 14L, 8L, 7L, 10L, 4L, 10L, 
3L, 1L, 9L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c("1", "2", "3", 
"4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "11", "12"))
```